# creating a list of character sting and bind with table

Tags: r

I have a database with some text string in one column and i want to make a list of all the string and separated it with comma.

only first comment is binding but i want to bind all the comments with comma separated

```
df <- data.frame("Dept"=c("OPS", "OPS",  "OPS",   "OPS",    "OPS",   "OPS",    "OPS",    "OPS",   "OPS",   "OPS",   "OPS",    "Sales",    "Sales",    "OPS",   "OPS",   "OPS",   "OPS",   "Sales",    "Sales"),
                 "Team"=c("Team1","Team2","Team3","Team2","Team1","Team2","Team3","Team2","Team1","Team2","Team3","Team2","Team1","Team2","Team1","Team2","Team1","Team2","Team1"),
                 "Sale1"=c(22,4,4,3,5,6,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,5),
                 "Sale2"=c(22,4,6,3,6,5,4,5,5,4,5,3,4,5,5,1,4,2,5),
                 "Comm"=c(NA,  "Regional is the location", "over all is ok", "Global part is partial",NA,NA, "Regional is the location",NA,   "Global",   "Regional is the location",NA, "Global part is partial",   "Global part is partial",NA, "Global",NA, "Global part is partial",NA,NA))

df1<- df %>% filter(Team == "Team3") 
T1 <- df1 %>% group_by(Dept) %>% summarise(mean=as.numeric(sprintf(round(mean(as.numeric(Sale1),na.rm = TRUE),2),fmt = '%#.1f')))



groupingvar <- "Dept"
com_var <- "Comm"
groupingvar <- rlang::parse_expr(groupingvar)
com_var <- rlang::parse_expr(com_var)

  Comments <- dat %>%
         group_by(!!groupingvar)%>% filter(!is.na(!!com_var)) %>% 
         summarise(Texts = gsub(",","",toString(coalesce(!!com_var),collapse = " ")))%>%
         select(-!!groupingvar) %>% unlist() %>% gsub("NA","", .) %>% stringi::stri_trim_both() 

  T1 <- cbind(T1,Comments)


# getting this error
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)debug at #68: T1
```

Comment: did you want to remove duplicate comments? say, within the same Dept and Team?

Comment: What is your expected output? It's not really clear.

Comment: You have not defined `dat`, and you have not shown us what your expected output looks like. I'm happy to try to help, but please try to answer those two issues. Thanks

Comment: Also, you code has currently shown, runs if you replace `dat` with `df1`, but I don't know if that is what you want or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this

```
df %>%
  group_by(Dept,Team) %>%
  summarize(
    mean1 = mean(Sale1),
    mean2 = mean(Sale2),
    comments = paste0(Comm[!is.na(Comm)], collapse=",")
  )
```

Output:

```
  Dept  Team  mean1 mean2 comments                                                                
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                                   
1 OPS   Team1  8     8.4  Global,Global,Global part is partial                                    
2 OPS   Team2  4.43  3.86 Regional is the location,Global part is partial,Regional is the location
3 OPS   Team3  4.33  5    over all is ok,Regional is the location                                 
4 Sales Team1  5     4.5  Global part is partial                                                  
5 Sales Team2  4     2.5  Global part is partial
```

Comment: `comments` is a comma-separated string of comments by Dept/Team, excluding NAs. 
 If you want these to be unique (Notice that OPS/Team1 has "Global" twice), you can change the `paste0()` call to `paste0(unique(Comm[!is.na(Comm)]), collapse=",")`